# No encoding declared

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I keep getting this error:

```
 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe4' in file /var/www/mooimom_django/mooimom_tw/models.py on line 716, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

because of:

```
subdistrict_destination_text    = models.CharField(verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('taiwan-models Shopping_Cart', "Subdistrict Destination Text"), max_length=255, default='100 中正區')
```

How to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this to top of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: For anyone reading this answer: your .py file has to be __effectively__ encoded in utf-8 for this "solution" to work - if it's in any other encoding this will not work as expected. Well, you _should_ be using utf-8 encoding anyway but if you don't, replace 'utf-8' with your effective file encoding.

Comment: no this wont work on my case. I'm using python 3 with no weird character in my codes. I'm calling this from my subprocess. p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-u', command[0]],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1, encoding='utf-8')

Comment: it worked great in my case, with python 3.7.3 in a Docker container.

Comment: Didnt fix my issue - SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 727: invalid start byte. Its complaining about a \n when printed to text file.